# How to measure the launch app time on firebase_ Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-performance

I need to show the Android app launch time on firebase, from the user clicks the icon, until seeing the first activity, need the launch time show on the firebase. How to do it?
Except for the performance on firebase, write yourself coding by firebase, how do it?
I think about using the timestamp, use the firebase database. But it seems it only can show the current time of your app on the firebase.

I searched the website, and already know the performance on Firebase, _app_start can show the app start time. but it is not very precise. We need to measure the exact time when users click the Android app icon until see the first activity page, need to write the coding to get the exact launch time. Then show the result on the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to show the Android app launch time on firebase, from the user clicks the icon, until seeing the first activity, need the launch time show on the Firebase. How to do it?

If you are interested in measuring the app’s launch time, most likely your application doesn't start as fast as you want and you need optimization. For that, I recommend you see the guide that exists at the following URL:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

If you perform some Firebase Realtime Database calls while opening the app, most likely on the splash page, then you should also consider using [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon), which is a service that can help you gain insight into the performance characteristics of your app, including the time that your app needs to start.

> But it seems it only can show the current time of your app on the firebase.

If you are thinking of a timestamp, that is generated on the server, and not on the client. So it doesn't help, because as far as I understand you need to know how long it will take your users from clicking the app's icon until they land on the first activity.

> We need to measure the exact time when users click the Android app icon until seeing the first activity page, need to write the coding to get the exact launch time. Then show the result on the firebase.

So most likely you can use one, or the other approach, or why not, a combination of them.

Comment: Hey lily. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?